# Postgresql ALL with IN

Tags: postgresql

Without using a subquery I'd like to find if all the elements in an array are equal to a subset of numbers.  So instead of `1 = ALL(ARRAY[1,1,1])` I want to do something like `ALL(ARRAY[1,1,1]) IN (1, 5)`.  Is this possible without using a select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `@>` operator.

```
-- does the column contain all of
select * from test_arrays where values @> array[6, 9];
select * from test_arrays where values @> '{6, 9}'::int[];
```

If you want to find where any 1 value of the array is in the other array use the `&&` operator:

```
-- does the column contain at-least one of
select * from test_arrays where values && array[6, 9];
select * from test_arrays where values && '{6, 9}'::int[];
```

I happened to write about this a couple of months ago.

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2016/05/07/postgresql-and-its-array-datatype/